# Graphics2D.hit method returns an unexpected boolean value

Tags: java, swing, detection, hittest

I originally attempted to perform a hit test on geometric shapes within a Canvas, checking if the mouse click position is within the bounds of the shape. However, the results were not as expected.

Therefore, I created a Minimal, Reproducible Example. The code snippet in this example creates a rectangle in the Canvas based on the mouse's position. When we select the 'select' RadioButton and click within the bounds of the rectangle on the Canvas, I expected the hit method to return true, but it actually returns false.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

class CanvasArea extends JPanel {
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
    MouseInputAdapter mode;
    Graphics2D storedG2d;

    CanvasArea() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 600));
    }

    void setRectangle(Rectangle r) {
        repaint(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.width + 1, rectangle.height + 1);
        rectangle = r;
        repaint(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.width + 1, rectangle.height + 1);
    }

    void setMode(MouseInputAdapter mode) {
        removeMouseListener(this.mode);
        this.mode = mode;
        addMouseListener(this.mode);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.draw(rectangle);
        storedG2d = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
    }
}

class RectangleListener extends MouseInputAdapter {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        HitTest.canvas.setRectangle(new Rectangle(e.getPoint(), new Dimension(100, 120)));
    }
}

class SelectListener extends MouseInputAdapter {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getPoint());
        System.out.println(HitTest.canvas.rectangle);
        Rectangle mousePosition = new Rectangle(e.getPoint(), new Dimension(1, 1));
        System.out.println(HitTest.canvas.storedG2d.hit(mousePosition, HitTest.canvas.rectangle, false));
    }
}

public class HitTest {
    static CanvasArea canvas = new CanvasArea();

    private Container createContentPane() {
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);

        JRadioButton rb1 = new JRadioButton("rectangle");
        rb1.addActionListener(e -> canvas.setMode(new RectangleListener()));

        JRadioButton rb2 = new JRadioButton("select");
        rb2.addActionListener(e -> canvas.setMode(new SelectListener()));

        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar(JToolBar.VERTICAL);
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        toolBar.add(rb1);
        group.add(rb1);
        toolBar.add(rb2);
        group.add(rb2);

        contentPane.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        contentPane.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return contentPane;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        HitTest hitTest = new HitTest();
        frame.setContentPane(hitTest.createContentPane());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(HitTest::createAndShowGUI);
    }
}
```

It can be observed that the mouse click position is within the bounds of the rectangle, but the hit method is returning false.
[image: output]

I used debugging to step into the hit method and noticed that the position and dimensions of the rectangle are being transformed (according to the documentation for [hit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#hit(java.awt.Rectangle,java.awt.Shape,boolean)) method, I assume it is transformed into device space, but I'm not sure). After the transformation, the rectangle does not intersect with the mouse click position, resulting in a false return value. I'm unsure how to proceed to get the correct result.

Comment: It's sort of working for me. What I would say is that your minrep is not quite min enough ;) The main thing is that you should not save `Graphics` instances as they are not valid outside their painting methods. I would get rid of the anonymous inner classes as they make for tricky code and nasty binaries. Private classes are better. Your hit testing would be simpler with `System.out.println(canvas.rectangle.contains(e.getPoint())? "HIT!" : "MISS!");
` although you should probably do something about that public global stuff (private classes will help).

Comment: The creation of the rectangle is a little surprising too - one expects a regular drag operation, followed by its being painted in the dimensions of choice. Someone using this might never see a rectangle - I almost didn't

Comment: While testing your code, I made the "target" a variable (`Rectangle hit = new Rectangle(e.getPoint(), new Dimension(1, 1));`) and passed this to `hit` and it worked.  Having said that, I've never actually used it, I've always used the `Shape` API directly - this saves you from having to maintain a reference to `Graphics` context, which is always a bad idea, and in your example, could lead to some memory leaks or undesirable GC overhead

Comment: *this saves you from having to maintain a reference to Graphics context,* @MadProgrammer, I'm not sure why one is necessary. There isn't one in the code I posted

Comment: @g00se Graphics2D storedG2d, which the op then references from a seperate class - thus is weird and troublesome to me

Comment: @g00se I use the hit method because in my project, I also need to perform a hit test on the outline of the geometry. To achieve this, I simply set the third parameter of hit to true. That's why I need to store the Graphics2D object.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Making the 'target' a variable didn't work for me...

Comment: _maintain a reference to Graphics context, which is always a bad idea, and in your example, could lead to some memory leaks or undesirable GC overhead._ @MadProgrammer, is there still a possibility of memory leaks when I use the create() method to create a "copy" of Graphics?

Comment: *I use the hit method because in my project, I also need to perform a hit test on the outline of the geometry.* The method used is not the issue. The issue is that you keep around an overhead of a stale graphics object. `Shape` has two `intersects` methods, neither of which rely on a graphics context

Comment: @Jacky Yes, because you never dispose it

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this...

```
class CanvasArea extends JPanel {
    Graphics2D storedG2d;
    //...
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //...
        storedG2d = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
    }
}
```

is a bad idea.  You shouldn't be holding onto a reference of the system `Graphics` context, to many things can simply go wrong.

I've never used `Graphics2D#hit`, I've always used the `Shape` API instead, which has it's own built in hit detection.

However, if I was going to use `Graphics2D#hit`, I would do so from within the `paintComponent` method, for example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MainPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {
        private DrawPane drawPane;

        public MainPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            drawPane = new DrawPane();

            add(drawPane);

            drawPane.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    drawPane.didHit(e.getPoint());
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public class DrawPane extends JPanel {

        private Rectangle rectangle;
        private Rectangle hitBounds;
        final private Dimension hitSize = new Dimension(1, 1);

        public DrawPane() {
            rectangle = new Rectangle(150, 150, 100, 100);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        // It's VERY important that the Point is within the context of the
        // this component, otherwise you will get werid results
        public void didHit(Point p) {
            hitBounds = new Rectangle(p, hitSize);
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            if (hitBounds != null) {
                if (g2d.hit(hitBounds, rectangle, false)) {
                    g2d.fill(rectangle);
                } else {
                    g2d.draw(rectangle);
                }
            } else {
                g2d.draw(rectangle);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

But that raises a bunch of new issues, as you should avoid having to much logic in the `paintComponent` ... and how do you flag/notify the fact that a hit occurred?

Instead, I'd make use the `Shape#contains(Point)` method for hit detection instead.  This can be done independently of the `Graphics` context and painting workflows, which make it easier to use as part of the "update" phase or for other conditional workflows.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MainPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {
        private DrawPane drawPane;

        public MainPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            drawPane = new DrawPane();

            add(drawPane);

            drawPane.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    drawPane.didHit(e.getPoint());
                }
            });
        }


    }

    public class DrawPane extends JPanel {

        private Rectangle rectangle;
        private boolean hit = false;

        public DrawPane() {
            rectangle = new Rectangle(150, 150, 100, 100);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        // It's VERY important that the Point is within the context of the
        // this component, otherwise you will get werid results
        public boolean didHit(Point p) {
            hit = false;
            if (rectangle.contains(p)) {
                hit = true;
            }
            repaint();
            return hit;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            if (hit) {
                g2d.fill(rectangle);
            } else {
                g2d.draw(rectangle);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

This would also allow you to decouple the management of the `Shape`s from the paint workflow, supporting concepts like "model-view-controller"

Comment: It's interesting that when I run the program using Graphics2D#hit, I noticed that even if I move the mouse outside the rectangle, the rectangle still appears to be filled. After conducting some tests, I found that the hit method tests a rectangle range that is offset further towards the bottom-right corner compared to the rectangle drawn on the DrawPane.

Comment: Based on these results, it seems consistent with the phenomenon mentioned in my initial question, which involves the device space coordinate transformation in the hit method. As device space coordinates are device-dependent, the variation in results occurs when the program is executed on different machines.